# Exclude outliers from any excel formula (numbers)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, statistics, analysis

I found a [great way to exclude outliers](http://archive.is/6enD8#selection-1113.1-1137.82) from a statistical excel formula, that requires only one row, such as AVERAGE.

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(AC4:AC22<>"",IF(AC4:AC22>=138,IF(AC4:AC22<=144,AC4:AC22))))}
```

But how can I use this IF-nesting for formulas that require two rows for Y and X values? The values for the IF evaluations would be in a third row.

Here is my example: 
Excel, calculate the INTERCEPT (X;Y) 
IF value in row Z ranges between 100 and 150

I tried another way. But it yields FALSE:

```
{=IF(AND(C4:C24>=138,C4:C24<=144,C4:C24<>""),INTERCEPT(B4:B24,A4:A24))}
```

Comment: anyone using excel in an other language, can translate the formula hereby: https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found the answer to my problem:

```
{=INTERCEPT(IF(C4:C26<>"",IF(C4:C26>=138,IF(C4:C26<=144,Y4:Y26))),X4:X26)}
```

And on your keyboard, use the shortcut Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter !